# Why does the table view automatically make a contentOffset its height is 20 p? in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

**Description:**

the center view belongs to a view controller. I added a the center view to  a view controller, the codes as follows:

```
 FNHAHChooseProjectController *chVC = [FNHAHChooseProjectController new];
    chVC.title = @"选择项目";
    self.containViewController =  [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:chVC];

    _containView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FNDeviceWidth*0.8, FNDeviceHeight*0.5)];
    _containView.cornerRadius = 10;
    [_containBgView addSubview:_containView];
    _containView.center = CGPointMake(_containBgView.width*0.5, _containBgView.height*0.5);

    [self addChildViewController:self.containViewController];
    self.containViewController.view.frame = self.containView.bounds;
    self.containViewController.view.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.containView addSubview:self.containViewController.view];
    [self.containViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

when I clicked the first cell to push a new view controller, the table view automatically made a contentOffset.I think the contentOffset's height is about 20 p,the statusBar's height.I don't know why it caused;

The UI effect is just like the gif as follows:
[image: userinterface]

Answer (score 1):

Select your viewController and uncheck the Adjust ScrollView Insets as shown below :)

[image]

This should solve your problem :)

Comment: The view controller I used is table view controller.If I uncheck the adjustScrollViewInset ,the navigation bar still cover the table view about 64 pixels. I had solved the problem with changing the animation for showing the center view.Anyway,thank you. @Sandeep Bhandari

Answer (score 1):

The 20 points is the `topLayoutGuide` of the `UIViewController`, you need to set the constraint of your content align to the `topLayoutGuide` of the `UIViewController`.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: YourContents
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:20.0];
```

With iOS 9 you can also create the NSLayoutConstraint this way:

```
[self.button.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
                                      constant:20.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: It didn't work. But I had solved the problem with changing the animation for showing the center view.Anyway,thank you.